# Selecting products sold to a given set of customers

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables, `product` and `sold_record`. `product` contains my list of products, while `sold_record` contains all of my transactions. How can I select a distinct list of products that both customer A and customer B bought?

Comment: what 'your lots' means ? I'm not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sold_record table has a product id and customer id, then the query would be:

```
select distinct s1.product_id 
 from sold_record as s1, sold_record as s2 
where s1.customer_id = "Customer A" 
  and s2.customer_id = "Customer B" 
  and s1.product_id = s2.product_id;
```

There may be a simpler way to do this using a join, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose table `Product` has a primary key `ProdID`, and table `Sold` a foreign key into `Product` by the same name as well as a `Customer` field (probably another foreign key into a third table `Customer`, but since you say there must be only two tables we'll assume a string that's the customer name, instead).  Then:

```
Select DISTINCT Product.ProdID
From Product
Inner Join Sold SA On (Product.ProdID=SA.ProdID
                       AND SA.Customer='A')
Inner Join Sold SB On (Product.ProdID=SB.ProdID
                       AND SB.Customer='B')
```

will give you the ProdID in question (of course, you can get other columns from that table, too, we just have no idea what those columns might be;-).